# How to use Django logging AdminEmailHandler outside of the app?

Tags: python, django, logging, cron

I have a Django web-site.
Also I have some scripts that launched by cron.

Scripts and Django share some code. Also they share logging configuration.
Logging configured via a big dict of string values as described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/

In my logging config I use handler `django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler` to notify admin via email about serious errors. It works inside the Django app but fails inside cron scripts: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

Is it possible to configure logging with emails inside the cron scripts?

Comment: You could make your cron scripts custom management commands - that would run them with the proper django configuration.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I can not convert my scripts to Django commands. Scripts must be executed in their own environment.

Comment: Ok then you just have to read the error message and do what it says : "you must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings"

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I did it before I post this question and got a bunch of other errors )) I'll try to configure it myself little bit later and publish the results here